# В чем разница между sdk, фреймворком и движком

Tags: framework, терминология, sdk, фреймворк, движок

Кто-нибудь может в чем разница между этими понятиями. К примеру, при разработке игр бывают sdk, фреймворки и движки.

Answer (score 6):

sdk - это набор разработчика, обычно от производителя операционной системы или большого сложного продукта, который позволяет делать свои расширения. Например, Android SDK.

Framework - это чуточку больше, чем просто набор функций и классов. В большинстве случаев это масштабные надстройки (часто над sdk), которые скрывают некоторые особенности нижележащей системы.

Движок - это готовый, часто небольшая библиотека, которая решает четко поставленную задачу и является строительным блоком. Например, движок физики. Но ему обычно побоку, как именно рисуется изображение и на айфоне или калькуляторе запускается программа.

Часто фреймворк или sdk уже содержит в себе несколько движков. Например, движок базы данных.

Ещё одно сравнение. Движок базы данных - это собственно база данных, а sdk к базе данных - это набор интерфейсов, классов, которые позволяют расширить ее возможности (а другие программы смогут воспользоваться этим). А фреймворк может в себе содержать набор функций и классов, которые не зависимо от нижележащей базы будут обеспечивать одинаковую работу с ней.

Comment: А я думал, что движок (двигатель) -- это что-то железное. Двигатель электрический, двигатель внутреннего сгорания, турбина... А "движок на php" -- что-то вроде "рации на бронепоезде"

Comment: @alexlz ну это распространенный слэнг, например "Smarty: PHP template engine". Надо всё-таки понимать контекст. А то framework это тоже строительные леса.

Comment: Ну не силён в лингвистике. Русским матерным владею свободно, а вот всякие умные движки на шаблонах -- мне уже тяжело.